# how to add service account key to codemagic

Tags: flutter, firebase, service-accounts, codemagic

I've been trying to use codemagic to deploy a flutter project from github to firebase distribution,
the problem is that it's not accepting the token anymore and saying that i've to use a service account key,

did anyone here tried to deploy a flutter project to firebase distribution with a service account?

when i try to add a script to codemagic.yaml it says that workflow is not configured!

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to add a service account key in `CodeMagic`.

**Bellow, I will explain step by step how you can set it up:**

1. Go to **Firebase** > **Select Your Project** > Go to **Project Settings**
2. Choose the **Service Accounts** tab and click **Generate new private key**
3. It will automatically download a **JSON** file. Keep it because it will be needed for the setup of **Codemagic**
4. Now go to **Codemagic** open your project and from **Environment Variables** add a new variable named `FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY`
5. Copy the contents of the service account key **JSON** file you downloaded from Firebase and paste it as the value for the `FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY` variable and save it.
6. Now update `codemagic.yaml` script.

To deploy to Firebase Distribution, you must add a script in your `codemagic.yaml` file.

If you encounter the "workflow is not configured" error, you must define a workflow in your `codemagic.yaml` file. Here's a basic example of a `codemagic.yaml` with a deployment script:

```
workflows:
  main:
    name: Main Workflow
    environment:
      # Add other environment variables if needed
      FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY: Encrypted(...) # Replace with the actual encrypted value
    scripts:
      # Add your build and test scripts here
      - name: Deploy to Firebase Distribution
        script: |
          # Install Firebase CLI
          npm install -g firebase-tools

          # Authenticate Firebase CLI with the service account key
          echo "$FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY" | base64 --decode > ./firebase_key.json
          firebase login --no-localhost --no-confirmation --service-account ./firebase_key.json

          # Build and deploy to Firebase Distribution
          flutter build apk # Replace with your build command
          firebase appdistribution:distribute ./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk # Replace with the path to your APK
```

Hope this will help you to add service account key to codemagic.

Comment: other env vars if needed, you mean i add the created env var and then if there are others?

Comment: Yes, there can be others!! But for now you need just one and that is Firebase service account key.